# How to open an application without using chdir and full path?

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

Is there any way to open an application without chdir and full path?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the full path... e.g.

c:\windows\system32\explorer.exe

OR

you can use a relative path (if you're in C:\windows\bob

..\system32\explorer.exe

OR

you can use

SET PATH = %PATH%;c:\windows\system32

(or set the Path variable through the System settings in Control Panel)

etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Watkins. I have a mistake, I am very sorry. I want to ask if there are other ways to open app without using cd AND full path. Sorry for wasting your golden time.

Comment: @user5567540 - You can also use the Path environment variable

Answer (score 0):

**On POSIX systems**

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin...
```

Any executable file in a directory listed can be called bare, for example, if `/usr/bin` is in your $PATH and `/usr/bin/myapp` is an executable file, then typing this will execute it:

```
$ myapp
Hello, world!
```